# How to insert an element into the middle of an array (json) in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert, sqlite-json1

I found a method `json_insert` in the json section of the SQLite document. But it seems to be not working in the way that I expected.

e.g. `select json_insert('[3,2,1]', '$[3]', 4) as result;`

The `result` column returns `'[3,2,1,4]'`, which is correct.

But for `select json_insert('[3,2,1]', '$[1]', 4) as result;`

I am expecting something like `'[3,2,4,1]'` to be returned, instead of `'[3,2,1]'`.

Am I missing something ? I don't see there is an alternative method to `json_insert`.

P.S. I am playing it on https://sqlime.org/#demo.db, the SQLite version is `3.37.2`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `select json_insert('[3,2,1]', '$[1]', 4)` returns `[3,2,1]` for me, running SQLite 3.35.5. What SQLite version are you running?

Comment: @Tomalak I am returning the same value as yours. What's why it bothers me. I am expecting something like `[3,2,4,1]` to be returned. . I am playing it on https://sqlime.org/#demo.db, the SQLite version is `3.37.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that `json_insert()` [will not overwrite values](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jins) (*"Overwrite if already exists? - No"*). That means you can't insert elements in the middle of the array.

My interpretation: The function is primarily meant to insert keys into an object, where this kind of behavior makes more sense - not changing the length of an array is a sacrifice for consistency.

You could shoehorn it into SQLite by turning the JSON array into a table, appending your element, sorting the result, and turning it all back into a JSON array:

```
select json_group_array(x.value) from (
    select key, value from json_each('[3,2,1]')
    union
    select 1.5, 4  -- 1.5 = after 1, before 2
    order by 1
) x
```

This will produce `'[3,2,4,1]'`.

But you can probably see that this won't scale, and even if there was a built-in function that did this for you, it wouldn't scale, either. String manipulation is slow. It might work well enough for one-offs, or when done infrequently.

In the long run, I would recommend properly normalizing your database structure instead of storing "non-blob" data in JSON blobs. Manipulating normalized data is much easier than manipulating JSON, not to mention faster by probably orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks! We are building a product similiar to the all-in-one note taking app Notion.so, it is a complex product, we are using PostgresSQL. We use jsonb data type to reduce the complexity of the database architect. We are planning to build a local version (single user) of the app, we consider using SQLite for the local version. JSON manipulation  of PostgreSQL is powerful, we are satisfied with it so far. It is hard for us to make big changes on database and application level. Didn't know that SQLite json manipulation is so weak. :-D Now we are under a little bit awkward position.

Comment: @Wenwu Well... It's generally a really bad idea do store living structured data in a JSON column, no matter how powerful the JSON manipulation capabilities of your RDBMS are. It's akin to storing CSV data in a VARCHAR column, just to cut corners in the database normalization. What's the point of running a relational DB engine when you store your data in opaque blobs? SQLite is not really at fault here, you're trying to do things that are outside of the intended usage pattern for relational databases.

Comment: @Wenwu Complex JSON manipulation is better done in application itself. If your application has internal state/complex items that you want to persist to SQLite, then the operations that manipulate that data should not be done at the persistence layer, but at the application layer. Since SQLite is so tightly integrated with the rest of the application code anyway, it should be easy to move that part a few lines out of the SQL string.